# Identical code behaves differently in two different classes in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-glide, shapeableimageview

I'm working on an Android application and I've run into a strange issue. I have two classes, `GoogleSignUpFragment` and `EmailSignUpFragment`, which both contain identical pieces of code for picking an image from the gallery and loading it into a ShapeableImageView using Glide.

The code in both classes works as follows:

1. An `Intent` is created to pick an image from the gallery.
2. In `onActivityResult()`, the Uri of the chosen image is retrieved.
3. Glide is used to load the image into a `ShapeableImageView`, with a circle crop applied.
4. There are methods to save temporary the image in order to load it into Firebase Storage.

During the debugging process, I've noticed that in `EmailSignUpFragment` everything runs smoothly. After the line `requestBuilder.into(target)`, execution moves to `override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {/* ... */}` as expected.

However, in `GoogleSignUpFragment`, after the line `requestBuilder.into(target)`, the execution jumps to `override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {/* ... */}`, and immediately afterwards the execution of the fragment stops.

This is the code that is identical in the two classes

```
private fun onPropicClick() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            selectedImageUri = data.data!!
            loadImageWithCircularCrop(selectedImageUri)
        }
    }

    private fun loadImageWithCircularCrop(imageUri: Uri?) {
        val requestBuilder = Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())

        val target = object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                croppedImageFile = saveBitmapToFile(resource)
                propicImageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                propicImageView.setImageDrawable(null)
            }
        }

        requestBuilder.into(target)
    }

    private fun saveBitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap): File {
        val file = File(requireContext().cacheDir, "propic.png")
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
        return file
    }
```

In the `OnCreateView` method of the Fragment i Have this line of code that starts the intent to choose the photo:

```
propicImageView.setOnClickListener { onPropicClick() }
```

- I've tried debugging both classes line by line, examining the execution flow. Given the identical code in both classes, I expected them to behave the same way
- I've also verified that my app has the necessary permissions to read external storage, and the same code works perfectly in the other class.
- I've tried using `if(!isAdded)` to check if the Fragment was not destroyed.
- I've tried using a ViewModel.
- I've tried using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`.
- I've tried this code with API 30 and API 32.